# How to iterate through interlaced modules (backbone.js) in jQuery templates?

Tags: collections, model, backbone.js, jquery-templates

I created a collection with interlaced models in backbone.js like this: (with for-loop)

```
var categories = new Category({ // main model
    title:  myJSON.category[h].title,
    product: []
});

var product = new Product({ // sub-model
        articleNumber:  myJSON.category[h].articles[j].articleNumber,
    shortDesc:  myJSON.category[h].articles[j].shortDesc,
    stock:      myJSON.category[h].articles[j].stock,
    price:      myJSON.category[h].articles[j].price,
    packaging:  myJSON.category[h].articles[j].packaging            
});
categoryCollection.add(categories); // my Collection
```

Then i created a view in backbone.js and used the the rendering from jQuery templates:

```
   render: function(){
        var col = {
            collection: categoryCollection.toJSON(),
        }
        var templ = $("#productTemplate").tmpl(col);
        $(templ).appendTo("#showProducts");
    }
```

So, here's the code from my html file

```
    <script id="productTemplate" type="text/x-jQuery-tmpl"> 
<div id="product_cat_1" class="product_table">
    <div class="site_links_top">
    </div>

    <!-- creating product categories in table -->
    {{each collection}}
    <a href="#product_cat_${$index + 1}" class="category category_closed"> 
            ${$value.title} </a>

            <table>
    <!-- creating products in table -->
    {{each ????? }} // i tried value, ${value}, ${$value} ....
                 // code..
    {{/each}}
    </table>
    {{/each}}

</div>
</script>
```

i don't know how to iterate through the second model ( product[] ). any ideas?

Comment: Not idea about _jquery template_ but a fast search brought me here: https://groups.google.com/group/knockoutjs/msg/3029be54fe2f69b8 can be related? I have check the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/QbuzX/) and it shows a _nested loop_ there.

Comment: the correct syntax for the second loop is:
{{each $value}} ... easier than expected :)